# [Android]Why can we still use setOutputFile(String path) of MediaRecorder?

Tags: android, android-source, android-mediarecorder, stagefright

I am trying to extract the muxer part of `MediaRecorder`, so I am learning the source code of Android 4.2.2 now, anyway, that is not important.
I have a questions here. It's about `setOutputFile(String path)` of `MediaRecorder.java`.

The call consequence of `MediaRecorder.java` is

```
MediaRecorder.java
  +- android_media_MediaRecorder.cpp
       +- MediaRecorder.cpp
            +- MediaPlayerService.cpp
                 +- MediaRecorderClient.cpp
                      +- StagefrightRecorder.cpp
```

But in the `StagefrightRecorder.cpp`, it says

```
status_t StagefrightRecorder::setOutputFile(const char *path) {
    ALOGE("setOutputFile(const char*) must not be called");
    // We don't actually support this at all, as the media_server process
    // no longer has permissions to create files.

    return -EPERM;
}
```

Then how can we continue to use `setOutputFile(String path)` of `MediaRecorder`? I really don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `MediaRecorder.java`, `setOutputFile` is handled at the `Java` layer itself without a corresponding native implementation. In the `Java` implementation, the [path is stored into `mPath`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaRecorder.java#671).

When `prepare` is called, [a `FileOutputStream` is created and passed to the native implementation of `setOutputFile`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaRecorder.java#691) which takes in a `File Descriptor` as can be observed from this implementation. This method i.e. taking in a `File Descriptor` is supported by the native implementation and hence, the output is generated and stored into the file system.

Hence, in examples such as `MediaRecorderTest.java`, one can observe that `MediaRecorder` object is initialized with a `string` for the output file path.